# Create RD Session remotely

Tags: remote-desktop, sharing, rdp, screencast

I'm trying to develop a project for customer support. It needs two-way screen sharing to be implemented. I tried using third party tools like team viewer, joinme, loginme, etc, but all of them installs an exe on client machine.How can i invoke a screen sharing without any installations on client side (something similar to webex)?

Please help.